# Submitting multipart form in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have the following javascript.

```
$("#CsvForm").unbind('submit').on('submit',function( event ){
    var formData = new FormData($(this[0]));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some url',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(json){
            console.log('ajax do something');
            ajax = true;
        },
        error: function(data) {
             console.log("failed");
        }
    });
});
```

My html form looks like this:

```
<form action="/teams/16/import_players" method="POST" id="CsvForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="E2lRbOD6hRQixJBNfsDL3Wamo4VzVnDj">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p><label for="id_csv_file">Upload CSV File:</label> <input class="form-control input-lg" id="id_csv_file" name="csv_file" placeholder="First Name *" required="true" type="file"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer ">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="width: 100%;">
        Upload
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that my formData returns and empty object literal and I get the javascript exception on submit saying:

"Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Help please.

Comment: this [link](http://blog.w3villa.com/websites/uploading-filesimage-with-ajax-jquery-without-submitting-a-form) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var fileData = $("#id_csv_file").prop("files")[0];   
var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append("file", fileData);
```

Here is complete [sample](http://blog.w3villa.com/websites/uploading-filesimage-with-ajax-jquery-without-submitting-a-form) code.

Comment: I still get the same an empty object and same error.                                 This is process data  false  formdata  FormData {}. Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: have you read the sample code? Copy the sample code and try it.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
$("#CsvForm").unbind('submit').on('submit',function( event ){
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("nameUsedOnServer",  document.getElementById("id_csv_file").files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'some url',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: "multipart/form-data",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(json){
        console.log('ajax do something');
        ajax = true;
    },
    error: function(data) {
         console.log("failed");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: @user875139 if any of the above answer solved your problem, then mark it as correct answer.